# A good source to understand interaction in LMM?

Tags: r, interaction, interpretation, lme4-nlme

I would like to know more about interaction in LMM using lmer. Can you recommend me any books, articles, websites?

Answer (score 3):

Bookwise: 
The uber-classic is [Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/ms/departments/sia/NLME/MEMSS/index.html) by Bates and Pinheiro; it shows its years at time but it is still an excellent read. I have also read [Generalized Linear Mixed Models: Modern Concepts, Methods and Applications](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781439815120) by Stroup; it is quite new and based on software I have never used (SAS) but it very well-written and clear. I like it a lot. I believe those two resources will cover most questions. I have also found [Linear Mixed Models: A Practical Guide Using Statistical Software](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781584884804) by West,  Welch and Galecki to be a good read but I would not pick it over the previous two. Finally [Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R](http://www.highstat.com/book2.htm) by Zuur, Ieno, Walker, Saveliev and Smith seems to be popular but I have not used personally.

The Centre for Multilevel Modelling (CMM) in the University of Bristol has a fuller web-catalogue of good books that can be found [here](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/support/books.html).

Paper-wise:
This list can be endless and probably you can find works specific to your field of application. Having said that the paper: [Generalized linear mixed models: a practical guide for ecology and evolution](http://facecouncil.org/puf/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Bolker-et-al-2009-TREE.pdf) by Bolker, Brooks, Clark, Geange, Poulsen, Stevens and White is pretty darn good (I like [TREE](http://www.cell.com/trends/ecology-evolution/home) papers).

And a side-comment:
Given [lmer](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/lme4/html/lmer.html)/[lme](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/nlme/html/lme.html)/[fitlme](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/fitlme.html)/[genstat](http://www.vsni.co.uk/software/genstat/htmlhelp/reml/LinearMixedModelsREML.htm) are coherent pieces of software, what you want is to understand how [Wilkinson notation](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2346786) works. There is not "magic" surrounding how you define interactions and nesting, just some rules that are (generally) not software-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Kris Preacher's [website](http://www.quantpsy.org/interact/index.html) (under "Hierarchical Linear Modeling") provides online tools to decompose either 2-way or 3-way interactions in LMMs, and distinguishes between same-level and cross-level interactions. Above each tool, he gives a brief tutorial for each type of interaction. He also provides references for further reading at the bottom.

EDIT:

I should also mention two books which should be useful. A reference in the field of LMMs is [Raudenbush & Bryk's (2002)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/076191904X) book (cited over 20,000 times according to Google Scholar). A more beginner-friendly book is that of [Hox (2010)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848728468). Both books are most relevant to the social sciences. A third book is very beginner-friendly as well, but concerns only LMMs as applied to longitudinal data (observations nested under participants): [Singer & Willett (2003)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005253FN2).

Since there is much overlap between interactions in LMMs and interactions in single-level regression, I would recommend [Cohen, Cohen, West, & Aiken's (2003)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805822232) book on linear regression (cited 30,000 times!). They talk at length about interactions involving different types of predictors (continuous, dummy coded), in very accessible fashion.

Comment: Patrick Coulombe, I have roughly read that website, but found that it is quite difficult to understand. Could I ask you why I need decompose three-way interaction?

Comment: I'll try to studied those sources. Thanks very much Patrick Coulombe.